# JavaScript action function as parameter

Tags: javascript, overriding, function-parameter

I've created a function that loops through an objects members, and their arrays as a separate function to be used as a util. In this function I would like to use a parameter; let's call it **action**, that is a reference to another function that manipulates strings, in the arrays of the object members being looped.
For instance I override String, using String.prototype.functionThatDoesSomething, so I can use it in the loop: arrayOfStrings[i].functionThatDoesSomething().

How would I pass a function like that into the util function as an argument?

Something like this is what I am after:

```
objLoop(myObj, String.prototype.functionThatDoesSomething); 

function objLoop(obj, action) {
    var modData = {};
    var list = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
        list = obj[key];
        var i,
            n = list.length;
        for (i=0; i<n; i+=1) {
            list[i] = list[i].action(); // e.g. functionThatDoesSomething()
        }
        modData[key] = list;
    }
    return modData;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "standard" way to be to use a wrapper function to accept and use the callback parameter(s) as appropriate;

```
objLoop(myObject, function (str) { return str.toLowerCaser(); });
```

And then use it as

```
list[i] = action(list[i]);
```

---

A slight alternative that may work (and works in this example) is to specify the *context* via [call/apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call);

```
objLoop(myObject, String.prototype.tolowerCase);
```

And then use it as

```
list[i] = action.call(list[i])
```

This requires that the supplied function works on the context, but it allows the original calling style to be used. (Libraries like jQuery often use a combination of specifying the context and additional parameters.)

---

A final approach is to supply a *string* as a property-name to resolve to the appropriate function to call. For example, called as so;

```
objLoop(myObject, "toLowerCase");
```

And then use it as

```
// note calling the parameter methodName vs action for distinction
list[i] = list[i][methodName]();
```

This is the least flexible (and least-idiomatic) approach out of the three shown, although it may be useful in certain cases.

Comment: Nice, I tried the with the "call", and it works very nice as well. When I use "[action]()", firebug says that action is not a function.

Comment: @user1121487 Yes, it has to be the *name* of the property that evaluates to the function to invoke. I've added another example.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to pass in the name of the prototype member:

```
function myCustomUpper() {
  return this.toUpperCase();
}

String.prototype.up = myCustomUpper;

var action = 'up';
'hello'[action]();
```

Comment: I've tried that, but firebug says: action is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to iterate the array.

You could end up with something like this:

```js
// return a new object that contains the same keys as object o
// but had function f called on each value
function myMap(o, f) {
    var new_o = {};
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function(k){
        new_o[k] = f.apply(o[k]);
    });
    return new_o;
}
```

```js
// E.g. call String.toUpperCase on an anonymous object containing two fields
myMap({ s1: 'string 1', s2: 'string 2' }, "".toUpperCase);
```